# formatted json format in php webservices

Tags: php, json, web-services

I am new in PHP. I am trying to format JSON. Here's the relevant code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM  `micards` m
JOIN user u ON m.`mobile` = u.phone");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $name = array('name'=>$row["name"],'email'=>$row["email"],'mobile'=>$row["mobile"]);
    $phone[] = array('phone'=>$row["phone"],array('card'=>$name));
    $response["contacts"] = $phone;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

I'm getting this output:

```
{
  "success": 1,
    "contacts": [{
      "phone": "919898989898",
      "0": {
        "card": {
          "name": "abcd",
          "email": "vwxy@test.com",
          "mobile": "919898989898"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "phone": "919898989898",
      "0": {
        "card": {
          "name": "abcd",
          "email": "rstp@test.com",
          "mobile": "919898989898"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "phone": "8686868686",
      "0": {
        "card": {
          "name": "pan",
          "email": "pnqr@gmail.com",
          "mobile": "8686868686"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "phone": "8686868686",
      "0": {
        "card": {
          "name": "monk",
          "email": "abcd@gmail.com",
          "mobile": "8686868686"
        }
      }
    }]
}
```

But I want it to be:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "contacts": [{
        "phone": "919898989898",
        {
            "card": {
                "name": "abcd",
                "email": "vwxy@test.com",
                "mobile": "919898989898"
            }
        },
        {
            "card": {
                "name": "abcd",
                "email": "rstp@test.com",
                "mobile": "919898989898"
            }
        }
    }],
    [{
        "phone": "8686868686",
        {
            "card": {
                "name": "panky",
                "email": "pnqr@gmail.com",
                "mobile": "8686868686"
            }
        },
        {
            "card": {
                "name": "panky",
                "email": "abcd@gmail.com",
                "mobile": "8686868686"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

What can I do to get the above output?

Answer (score 0):

just change this part:

```
$phone[] = array('phone'=>$row["phone"],array('card'=>$name));    
$response["contacts"] = $phone;
```

to

```
$response["contacts"][] = array('phone'=>$row["phone"],array('card'=>$name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste this code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $name = array('name'=>$row["name"],'email'=>$row["email"],'mobile'=>$row["mobile"]);
    $response["contacts"][] = array('phone'=>$row["phone"],array('card'=>$name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
$phone[] = array('phone'=>$row["phone"],array('card'=>$name)) to 
$phone[] = array('phone'=>$row["phone"],'card'=>$name)
;
```

Comment: thanks for all of you support .But it doesnot working with above solutions

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is a problem with associative arrays and the way you are packing it. You can try to organize your response array like this:

```
$response = [
    'success'=>1,
    'contacts'=>[
        'phone'=>$row['phone'],
        'card'=>[
            'name'=>$row['name'],
            'email'=>$row['email'],
            'mobile'=>$row['mobile']
        ]
    ]
];
```

It should work, didn't check it out thou.